# Android SQLite, How to know if a sqlite field is NULL or 0?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

for example, there is a student table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (name TEXT, grade INTEGER);
```

and I insert an entry:

```sql
INSERT INTO students(name) VALUES('Allen');
```

And you can see the grade is NULL.
In Android, I use these code to read the table:

```java
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT grade FROM students WHERE name = 'Allen'", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
long serverId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("grade"));
//the serverId is 0
cursor.close();
```

I found the cursor.getLong returns 0, but the real values in SQLite is NULL. So how can I distinguish between the 0 and the NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("grade"))` to tell if the column is null